# Returning all row values when other rows meet criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to return a list of all the results in Row 3 that match results in a row that are over a particular number. In this case over 21. So I am looking for a formula that basically reads if year = 2021, week = 3 and results in table > 21, then return data in row 3. Using the example data it would return "540138" and "540141" since those are the two results over 21 in Week 3.  [image: example of table and potential results]

Comment: Stack overflow is a place for suggestions, tips and best practices. Please try to start working on the solution yourself, provide what have you tried till now and seek help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER` if you have the newest version of Excel.

Something like: `=FILTER($E$3:$I$3, $E6:$I6>21)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Excel-365` then try below formula

```
=FILTER($E$3:$I$3,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($D$4:$D$8),1,0),(C4:C8=2021)*(D4:D8=3)*(E4:I8>21)))
```

[image]

For older version you may try-

```
=INDEX($E$3:$I$3,,SMALL(IF(($C$4:$C$8=2021)*($D$4:$D$8=3)*($E$4:$I$8>21),COLUMN($E$4:$I$8)-COLUMN($D$4),""),COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)))
```

This is an array formula. So, you need to enter the formula with CSE means `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.